# My html site mobile view in iPhone shadow CSS not working correctly

Tags: html, css, iphone, bootstrap-4, responsive

[image]

This is my iPhone view on my site. how can I fix this? I need to remove this shadow

Comment: You need to show your code, without it we can only speculate.

Comment: Yes. Please provide a minimal reproducible example.